# Parameters in c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

Function template example

```
template<typename T, int n>
T max(T (&arr)[n])
{
   T maxm = arr[0];
   for(int i = 1; i <n; ++i)
      if (maxm < arr[i])
       maxm = arr[i];

   return maxm;
}
```

Is **arr** also a type parameter like **T** ?

Answer (score 5):

`arr` is a name of a function parameter. It's not a type parameter. Its type is a reference to an array of element type `T` and length `n`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is `arr` also a type parameter like `T` ?

No `arr` is a call parameter. It is neither a type parameter nor a non-type parameter

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is a usual function parameter which is passed a variable when the function is called.

However, the *type* of that argument is used to determine `T` and `n`, which *are* template parameters. So in a way, `arr` is used to link the function argument to the template arguments.

This process is called *type deduction*.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is function parameter, which type is deduced from `T` and `n`.

Think about changing your code to:

```
template<typename T, int n>
T max(T (&arr)[n])
{
   T* maxel = &(arr[0]);
   for(int i = 1; i <n; ++i)
      if (*maxel < arr[i])
       maxel = &(arr[i]);

   return *maxel;
}
```

In your version if you'll gave some array of objects that are bigger as index rises every time copy ctor would be called - and that could be somehow expensive, depending of `T` type.